# NFS mounts without automounter, which seems to grab everything

Tags: macos, automount, nfs

We have some NFS mounts we place in the fstab, via "vifs" which we want to manage separate of the autofs subsystem.    The mounts were created in a separate location (/mnt) which should not be managed by the automounting system.   But it appears that no matter where you place a mount, somehow the autofs/automount subsystem grabs ahold of it and tries to remount it when you unmount it.

This is a big problem and I'm trying very hard to figure out why and how to fix it.   I wonder if there is a flag in the /etc/auto* files that might have to do with this?   Something else?

Does someone know how to get around this annoying behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: I do have a similar problem! I mounted manually in my home folder (~/Projects/mnt) a NFS share, and somehow the some service grabbed that mount point and keep on remounting it with an annoying popup when I am on a different network. If you find the solution, please post it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you. If all your looking to do is save the connection information, finder will solve that problem. http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22243
Just add it your list of favorite servers and it's point and click. The information appears to be outdated, but I'm sure the process is still similar.

I just checked and there is another way to mount NFS shares:

```
$cd /net/"ip or computer name"
```

and browse the shares.

You can easily write a script to do this for you. I can confirm that the above method does work, because I tested it in Lion, and I read about this technique in a book I think is based on Tiger/Leopard.

EDIT: **Here is an output of my /etc/auto_master file**

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-          -static
```

I'm guessing you would delete the last two lines according to the manual.  [Disclaimer: I have never tried this].  Here is a link the auto_master documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/auto_master.5.html

> EDIT: http://lowendmac.com/ed/winston/09kw/intro-to-autofs.html Here
>   it describes the last two entries
>
> The last two lines in auto_master handle NFS mounts defined in the
>   /etc/fstab file, the common file system mount table in Linux and other
>   Unix flavors. The /etc/fstab file is deprecated in OS X and not
>   recommended.
>   I would try commenting them out one at a time and see if that helps

Comment: Let me clarify, the behavior I'm looking for is for a standard fstab entry.  But reading around, it seems that somehow OS X ties in the autofs and network mounts such that it will grab anything in /etc/fstab.  That's all fine and good, but when I go to manually unmount, it happily remounts (as automounter does) and I don't want that behavior.  It's really irritating. :-)  If I umount something manually, I expect it to STAY that way until I mount it again.